# Microsoft Teams custom connector doesn't display a themeColor

Tags: webhooks, office365connectors, microsoft-teams

When trying to create a custom webhook for microsoft teams, I'm trying to define a "themeColor" in my payload that is sent to my connector. For some reason though, microsoft teams doesn't display any theme color on in response in the Teams application, it just looks like this:

[image]

This is what my payload looks like, I'm pretty sure it's formatted correctly:

```
            var officeObject = {"title": htmlTitle,
                                "summary": "Nothing",
                                "themeColor": "FF0000",
                                "sections":[
                                    {
                                        "facts": [
                                            {
                                                "name":"Issue:",
                                                "value": issueTitle
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "name":"Description:",
                                                "value": description
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            };
```

Any idea why microsoft teams wont display a theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Teams does not currently support themeColor property on connector messages.

Comment: ): Ok, are there plans to add this feature in the future? Would be really nice to be able to distinguish different webhooks with different colors..

Comment: Sorry, I can't comment on when this would land :)

Comment: for the record, this feature was added but has recently been removed again :/